# How to i check if a user input is in a list, and get its list number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im like 3(recent) days into python (about 2 weeks total); i want to make a script to translate from english to dovahzul,  and vice versa. Feel free to tell me ways to make what ive already done easier, or give me a module that could help;  though, im using pythonista so that may not be an option.

```
english = ['the','quick','brown']
dovahzul = ['faal','nel','prun']

text = input()

def translate_eng():
    print('eng')
    return

def translate_dov():
    print('dov')
    return

if text in english:
    translate_eng()
else:
    translate_dov()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in real life, word-by-word translation will require a dictionary.

```
english_to_dovahzul = {
    'the': 'faal',
    'quick': 'nel',
    'brown': 'prun'
}

def translate(text, dictionary, filler=None):
    return ' '.join([dictionary.get(word, filler or word) for word in text.split()])

print(translate('the quick brown fox', english_to_dovahzul, filler='?'))
```

### Output

```
faal nel prun ?
```

You will extend your language by adding words to the dictionary.

To get the inverse translation, you can invert your dictionary like so.

```
dovahzul_to_english = {v: k for k, v in english_to_dovahzul.items()}
```

Of course, modern translation is far from using word-by-word like this, but it seems to be enough for your purpose.

Comment: Is there an easy way to reverse it?

Comment: And yeah, theres a translator on the thuum site, i just want the experience. I dont like courses to learn coding,  so im just gonna do useless, overcomplicated things

Comment: @Reconer_000 Yes, I added details as to how to inverse the dictionary

Comment: @Reconer_000 If your a dedicated you can learn by yourself no worries!

Comment: Thanks! "7 more to go..." why even have a character minimum